# Exit a gtkmm application properly

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I am creating a GUI using Glade, and am able to connect signals to it properly. I am trying to have a button that simply quit the application.

The doc is not very clear on how to do so. On some forums you should do:

```
Gtk::Main::quit();
```

Which does exit my application, but with a Segmentation Fault. Apparently I am supposed to call quit() directly from my application, like so:

```
p_application->quit();
```

But this returns me the resulting error at compile time:

```
error: invalid use of member ‘GUI::p_application’ in static member function
     Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> p_application;
                                    ^
error: from this location
     p_application->quit();
     ^
```

I created the application using this:

```
 p_application = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.app.app");
```

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to access the `p_application` member of your `GUI` class from a static member function of `GUI`.

You can't access members from static functions, since there is no instance. Change the function to not be static, or get hold of an instance and access the member on that.

Comment: The problem is, this function need to be static otherwise I can't connect it to a button's signal.

Comment: Use `sigc::mem_fun` or whatever the API is in glibmm to use a member function as a signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: All the online documentation I could find is for gtkmm-4. If you are stuck using gtkmm-3.0 for Ubuntu, download your own docs from the repository (see below). I've included links to gtkmm-4 documentation in the hopes that they are helpful; use at your own risk.

Here is a working solution for gtkmm-3.0. Compile with:

```
 g++ helloworld.cc -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0`
```

Code:

```
// In file helloworld.cc
// sigc::mem_fun is the important part:
// it lets you turn a member function into a static one (or something).
// I don't really get it.
// I got most of the code here from https://www.gtk.org/docs/language-bindings/cpp

#include <iostream>

#include <sigc++/sigc++.h>            // Unnecessary, because the gtkmm modules also include mem_fun.
#include <glibmm/refptr.h>            // The wrapper object that Application::create returns.

#include <gtkmm/application.h>        // C++ wrapper for C's gtk_main.
#include <gtkmm/button.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>

class HelloWorld : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    HelloWorld(Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application>);

protected:
    void on_button_clicked();

    Gtk::Button m_button;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app;
};


// Constructor for window class. app should be a pointer to the Application instance you made in main.
HelloWorld::HelloWorld(Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app)
: m_button("Quit this program")     // Sets button label. I have no idea what this syntax is. C++ be whack, yo
{
    this->app = app;
    // mem_fun does most of the magic. How does it work? idk lol
    m_button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
                            &HelloWorld::on_button_clicked));
    add(m_button);
    m_button.show();
}

void HelloWorld::on_button_clicked()
{
    std::cout << "Exiting the program now." << std::endl;
    this->app->quit();
    std::cout << "Note: Program doesn't actually end until this function finishes." << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");
    HelloWorld helloworld(app);
    return app->run(helloworld);
}
```

My thoughts: I don't really get it?

`Gtk::Button.signal_clicked()` [(reference)](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Button.html#a53fcbe39d09fde964876d730218cb46f) returns a `Glib::SignalProxy<void()>`. SignalProxy [(reference)](https://developer-old.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1SignalProxy_3_01R_07T_8_8_8_08_4.html) has template <R(T...)>, which I think describes the kind of functions that can be connected--in this case, with a return type `void` and an empty list `()` of arguments. `SignalProxy.connect()` returns something I'll ignore, and accepts either a `SlotType&` or a `SlotType&&` (I have no idea what the difference is) where `SlotType` is `sigc::slot<R(T...)>`, or in this case `sigc::slot<void()>`.

`sigc::slot<R(T...)>` [(reference)](https://developer-old.gnome.org/libsigc++/stable/classsigc_1_1slot_3_01T__return_07T__arg_8_8_8_08_4.html) seems pretty fundamental. It looks like it's just a wrapper that holds a function (presumably, so SignalProxy can store it to be called later when the button is clicked). Up until now, it all makes sense.

The notes on `sigc::mem_fun` [(reference)](https://developer-old.gnome.org/libsigc++/stable/group__mem__fun.html#ga5d28dcf1bb88830a6e50d08d1fe7ec08) say that it returns a `sigc::mem_functor`, which sounds reasonable but `mem_functor` does not seem to fulfill what `SignalProxy.connect()` wants: `sigc::slot` and `sigc::mem_functor` do not inherit from each other. Baffling. I guess there's some kind of undocumented type coercion going on here? Maybe? The other lead is that mem_fun apparently returns an object of type `decltype(auto)`? Which I tried reading [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) on, and then they started talking about lvalues and unparenthesized id-expressions, and that's when my eyes glazed over. Looking at the old documentation, there used to be like 70 overloaded versions of mem_fun to do what one version can do now, so I guess `decltype` is doing its job. But the point is, that's where I gave up.

`decltype(auto)` and `mem_functors` are C++ deep-magic. `mem_fun` does the thing `SignalProxy.connect()` needs, and that's all I know.

References:

[gtkmm-4.0 documentation](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/)

[glibmm documentation](https://developer-old.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/)

[sigc++ documentation](https://developer-old.gnome.org/libsigc++/stable/)

[gdk documentation in c](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/) << gtkmm refers to stuff like "GdkEventKey" and enumerations from the header <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>. I couldn't find a c++ reference for this, or anything like "gdkmm". I think maybe gtkmm just uses the C structs for events directly?

Installing documentation: I'm on Ubuntu, 20.04.3 LTS. You can install html documentation for gtk 3.0 from the repository. Do `sudo apt install libgtkmm-3.0-doc libglibmm-2.4-doc libsigc++-2.0-doc`. To find out where the index file is for, for example, gtkmm, do `dpkg -L libgtkmm-3.0-doc | grep index`. sigc++ has multiple index files, two of which are traps. I could not figure out where the documentation for GDK is, possibly because there isn't any in the repository. Use the online stuff instead.